# Keep history of New Relic metrics

Tags: .net, sql-server, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have New Relic set up and recording metrics across our .net application and using the SQL Server plugin to capture additional detail on the DB.

At present we keep 7 days history and understand in the Pro version we can keep up to a month.

I need to compare stats from over a year a ago to get a view on long term performance. Is there a way to keep or export data in some way?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is via the API

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/how-can-i-export-data-from-new-relic/135

Thanks to NR support team